# "Train crossing mutex problem" - Getting NULL on last 2 lines

Tags: c, mutex

Hey I'm having trouble solving a bug that causes some unwanted NULL's to be displayed in my final output. When you run the program enter a string such as 'nnseeeewwwew' into the command line before running.

Here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <string.h>

/* mutex */
pthread_mutex_t thisMutex;

/* Condition Variables */
sem_t nQueue, eQueue, sQueue, wQueue;
int nFirst, sFirst, eFirst, wFirst;
int done = 0;

/* Thread Prototypes */
void *bats(void *);
void *checking(void *);

/* Prototypes */
void arrive(int num, char *dir);
void cross();
void leave(int num, char *dir);
void check();

/* Global pointer to argv */
char *directions = NULL;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i = 0,
    n = 0,
    s = 0,
    e = 0,
    w = 0;

    directions = argv[1];
    while(  argv[1][i] == 'n' || argv[1][i] == 'e' ||
          argv[1][i] == 's' || argv[1][i] == 'w' )
    {
        if(argv[1][i] == 'n'){n++;}
        if(argv[1][i] == 's'){s++;}
        if(argv[1][i] == 'e'){e++;}
        if(argv[1][i] == 'w'){w++;}
        i++;
    }


    pthread_mutex_init(&thisMutex, NULL);
    sem_init(&nQueue, 0, n);
    sem_init(&sQueue, 0, s);
    sem_init(&eQueue, 0, e);
    sem_init(&wQueue, 0, w);
    nFirst = sFirst = eFirst = wFirst = 0;

    pthread_t tid[i];
    pthread_t checker;

    pthread_create(&checker, NULL, checking, NULL);

    for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
    { pthread_create(&tid[j], NULL, bats, (void*) &j); }

    for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
    { pthread_join(tid[j], NULL); }

    done = 1;

    pthread_join(checker, NULL);

    pthread_mutex_destroy(&thisMutex);
    sem_destroy(&nQueue);
    sem_destroy(&sQueue);
    sem_destroy(&wQueue);
    sem_destroy(&eQueue);

    return 0;
}


void *checking(void *arg)
{
    while( done == 0 )
    {
        if( nFirst == 1 || sFirst == 1 ||
           eFirst == 1 || wFirst == 1 )
            check();
    }
    exit(0);
}

void *bats(void *arg)
{
    int index = *(int *)arg;
    char *dir;
    switch (directions[index])
    {
        case 'n':
            dir = "North";
            break;
        case 's':
            dir = "South";
            break;
        case 'e':
            dir = "East";
            break;
        case'w':
            dir = "West";
            break;
    }
    arrive(index, dir);
    leave(index, dir);
    _exit(0);
}

/* Functions */
void arrive(int num, char *dir)
{
    printf("BAT %d from %s arrives at crossing\n", num, dir);
    if(strcmp(dir,"North")== 0)
    {
        sem_wait(&nQueue);
        nFirst = 1;
        while(eFirst == 1){ /* do nothing */ }
        cross();
        nFirst = 0;
        sem_post(&nQueue);
    }
    else if(strcmp(dir,"West")== 0)
    {
        sem_wait(&wQueue);
        wFirst = 1;
        while(nFirst == 1){ /* do nothing */ }
        cross();
        wFirst = 0;
        sem_post(&wQueue);
    }
    else if(strcmp(dir,"South")== 0)
    {
        sem_wait(&sQueue);
        sFirst = 1;
        while(wFirst == 1){ /* do nothing */ }
        cross();
        sFirst = 0;
        sem_post(&sQueue);
    }
    else if(strcmp(dir,"East")== 0)
    {
        sem_wait(&eQueue);
        eFirst = 1;
        while(sFirst == 1){ /* do nothing */ }
        cross();
        eFirst= 0;
        sem_post(&eQueue);
    }
}

void cross()
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&thisMutex);
    sleep(1);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&thisMutex);;
}

void leave(int num, char *dir)
{
    printf("BAT %d from %s leaving crossing\n", num, dir);
}

void check()
{
    if( nFirst == 1 && sFirst == 1 &&
       eFirst == 1 && wFirst == 1 )
    {
        eFirst = 0;
        sleep(1);
        eFirst = 1;
    }
}
```

The goal of this assignment is to

1. BATs arriving from the same direction line up behind the first BAT already at the crossing;
2. BATs arriving from the right always have the right of way (unless the waiting BAT receives a signal to go);
3. Deadlock has to be prevented
4. Starvation has to be prevented

Once you run the code, you'll see the last two lines have 'NULL' for the direction the BAT is arriving from. Need help to solve that issue

Thanks!

Comment: `dir` is a `char` pointer. So you cannot directly use an equality sign like `if( dir == "North")` What you need is `if ((strcmp(dir,"North")== 0)`

Comment: I replaced the if statements, still getting NULL error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program has undefined behaviour becasue you are passing pointer to local variable into your thread function. In `bats` function when dereferencing pointer you may get garbage value:

```
   for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
    { 
      pthread_create(&tid[j], NULL, bats, (void*) &j); 
    }
```

`j` is local inside *for* loop.

You could allocate memory to hold value for int
 variable:

```
   for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
    { 
      int* var = malloc(sizeof(int));
      *var = j;
      pthread_create(&tid[j], NULL, bats, var); 
    }
```

remember to free this memory in `bats` function:

```
void *bats(void *arg)
{
    int index = *(int *)arg;
    //...
    leave(index, dir);
    free (arg); // <--
    pthread_exit(NULL); // instead of _exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Solved the null issue. I'm seeing the last line of the program saying "BAT 0 from North leaving crossing" Any reason why 0 is waiting until the very end to leave?

Comment: @BobbyWidThaTool `_exit(0)` close your program while joining at first thread, you should call `pthread_exit(NULL)` instead of _exit(0).

Comment: you're a legend. Thanks! Running perfect now. Man I wish I was good at C

Answer (score 0):

1. `dir` is a char pointer. So you cannot directly use an equality sign like `if( dir == "North")` What you need is `if ((strcmp(dir,"North")== 0)`
2. in the loop below,

   ```
   while(  argv[1][i] == 'n' || argv[1][i] == 'e' ||
         argv[1][i] == 's' || argv[1][i] == 'w' )
   {
       i++;
       if(argv[1][i] == 'n'){n++;}
       if(argv[1][i] == 's'){s++;}
       if(argv[1][i] == 'e'){e++;}
       if(argv[1][i] == 'w'){w++;}
   }
   ```

You are incrementing `i` first inside the loop. So, for the last element in the array `argv[1][i]` you are reading junk values. The increment of `i` should be the last statement in the loop. i.e. after `if(argv[1][i] == 'w'){w++;}`

Comment: Made these changes, now I still get NULL on the last 'arrive' statement and segmentation fault after that

Comment: ok I pasted my new code in the original post. See if I still have a mistake in there please, thanks!